# Galaxy S4 SupportActionBar covers whole screen in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, galaxy, samsung-mobile

The Samsung Galaxy S4 shows a very weird behavior when going into ACtionMode on my app which is using SupportActionBar from Support-v7.

[image]

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

I guess the issue comes from Samsung custom Android-Rom.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can you tell what exactly is the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect its a bug in Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode on certain Samsung devices. In the Light theme this doesnt seem to be present. ( Check answer )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this changing the parent of my custom actionmode theme from:

```
<style name="MyApp.Widget.ActionMode"  parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
```

to:

```
<style name="Apo.Widget.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionMode.Inverse">
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason those themes don't seem valid in the latest AppCompat libraries (I tried Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode.Light.Inverse, but it didn't fix the issue)

Instead if you are registered for orientation changes, you can override onConfigurationChanged(...) in your custom view and re-set the proper height parameters on the layout params. This reliably works to prevent the full-screen issue.