# Android contextual action bar displays incorrect

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use Appcompat v21.0.3.0

On Genymotion (Android 4.0.5), Samsung GT-I8730 (4.1.2) and Sony Xperia Z3 (5.0.2) [contextual action bar displays as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwspf.png).

But on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (4.4.2) and Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.4.4) [it displays strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxCAB.png).
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514727/galaxy-s4-supportactionbar-covers-whole-screen-in-actionmode), but this solution doesn't working in my case.

I solved this problem by adding a base style for Action mode and inherited from it

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode">
<item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
<item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style> 

<style name="MyTheme.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.ActionMode">
    ....
</style>
```